# When $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1f(x)\sin(nx)=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

What is a good sufficient condition for $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1f(x)\sin(nx)dx=0$$

If $f$ is differentiable then by integral by part we can easily prove. But I think differentiablity is a too strong condition. Can we make it less strict?

Comment: Yes, use $$\left\lvert \int_0^1 f(x)\sin (nx)\,dx - \int_0^1 g(x)\sin (nx)\,dx\right\rvert \leqslant \int_0^1 \lvert f(x) - g(x)\rvert\,dx.$$

Comment: Lebesgue integrability is enough. See [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-LebesgueLemma.html).

Comment: @DanielFischer How do you proceed further?

Comment: You approximate an integrable function by a continuously differentiable function in the integral norm to obtain the conclusion for all integrable functions.

Comment: Yeah I understand that argument!
Is there any other nice way to show directly by some calculations?

Comment: Continuity is enough (since it implies uniform continuity over a compact interval), square-integrability is enough (due to Parseval's identity), Riemann- or Lebesgue- integrability are enough.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105258/integral-involving-a-periodic-function

Answer (score 2):

To be sure that everything makes sense, we assume that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable.

If we show the result for the characteristic function of a Borel subset, it OK. And by approximation, we can do it for finite disjoint unions of intervals, for which the result is true.

Hence $f$ Lebesgue integrable is a sufficient condition.

Comment: I really don't understand anything but thanks, I can see the beauty :)

Comment: I guess you did not study yet measure theory.

Comment: Yes I haven't. I hope to obtain a beautiful proof in the case of continuity maybe and in the context of normal Riemann integral. Hope I will get to measure theory in the future...

Answer (score 1):

I'm inspired by another answer here

[Computing $\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \int_{a}^{b}\left ( f(x)\left | \sin(nx) \right | \right )$ with $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328314/computing-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-int-ab-left-fx-left-sinnx)

So I will write down a proof for $f$ continous.

Take $I_n=\int_0^1f(x)\sin(nx)dx=\int_0^1g(x)dx$

We have

$$I_n=\int_0^{\pi/n}g(x)dx+\int_{\pi/n}^{2\pi/n}g(x)dx+\dots+\int_{(k-1)\pi/n}^{k\pi/n}g(x)dx+\int_{k\pi/n}^1g(x)dx$$

where $1-\frac{k\pi}{n}<\frac{\pi}{n}$ or $k=[\frac{n}{\pi}]$.

Using mean value theorem we have

$$\int_{(i-1)\pi/n}^{i\pi/n}f(x)\sin(nx)dx=f(u_i)\int_{(i-1)\pi/n}^{i\pi/n}\sin(nx)dx=\frac{f(u_i)}{n}\int_{(i-1)\pi}^{i\pi}\sin ydy=2\frac{f(u_i)}{n}(-1)^i$$

with $u_i\in [(i-1)\pi/n,i\pi/n]$.

Therefore we have:

$$I_n=\sum_{i=1}^k2\frac{f(u_i)}{n}(-1)^i+\int_{k\pi/n}^1g(x)dx$$
$$I_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{i=1}^{[k/2]}\frac{2\pi f(u_{2i})}{n}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{i=1}^{[(k+1)/2]}\frac{2\pi f(u_{2i-1})}{n}+\int_{k\pi/n}^1g(x)dx$$

Then using the definition of Riemann Integral we have:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} I_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^1f(x)dx-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^1f(x)dx+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{k\pi/n}^1g(x)dx$$

$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{k\pi/n}^1g(x)dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(v)\int_{k\pi/n}^1\cos(nx)dx=0$$

where $v\in[k\pi/n,1]$ (since $|\int_{k\pi/n}^1\cos(nx)dx|\le 1-k\pi/n<\pi/n$ and $f$ is continous so $|f(v)-f(1)|$ is small enough)

Is this proof true?